# I have aluminum 12 2 wiring i want to add an extra light Daisy chain what gauge/amp copper wire do i use for a 3 ft span, i will be using alumiconns

Tags: electrical, wiring, aluminum-wiring

Adding 1 extra light total of 2 on circuit. Need to know what gauge of copper wire to add to aluminum 12-2 gauge 3’ span.

I will use AlumiConn connectors

Answer (score 4):

### You'll want 14/2 NM...

The rule for converting between aluminum and copper wire gauges is that in order to carry a given amount of current, you need an aluminum wire two sizes larger than the copper wire you would have used.  So, a 12AWG aluminum wire is rated for the same 15A as a 14AWG copper wire is, and NM is apropos since jurisdictions that don't permit NM also generally don't permit the use of aluminum, especially at branch-circuit gauges.

### ...and a torque screwdriver

While your choice of AlumiConns for this job is a good one, as they are the most reliable way of making an aluminum-to-copper branch circuit wiring connection available to the rest of us, they, like all mechanical setscrew splice/tap connectors, are sensitive to tightening torque.  As a result, a using an inch-pound torque screwdriver to tighten the connector screws to the manufacturer's specified torque value is *highly* recommended for long-term reliable results.

(Sidenote: if you're having trouble with the relatively chunky Alumiconns taking up too much room in the box, get a Wiremold ceiling starter box and use it as an *extension ring* to add extra volume.)

Comment: C'mon upvoters, this is a good answer!

Comment: Just as an FYI, they do have a non-torque method too (quarter turn past resistance, if memory serves), but the torque is preferred. I bought a torque screwdriver to do mine (I still work with them from time to time in my house) and it was prohibitively expensive for a one-off project.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for the minimum size wire allowed are determined by the size of the overcurrent protection (i.e. the breaker or fuse). The maximum overcurrent protection allowed for #12 aluminum is 15A, the minimum size copper for 15A is #14. You can use larger than #14 if convenient, but must use the size of overcurrent protection that matches lowest rated wire in the circuit.